# Revolving Slider with JSON

Tags: css, angularjs, json

I want to create something like this: http://codepen.io/cassidoo/pen/MyaWzp. However, in this the number of cycles are set at 5. I want to read in data from a json. For example, if my json has a bunch of quotes, then inside the div I would have:

```
<div class="quote">{{ parsed['quotes'] }}</div>
```

The trouble I'm having is how to make it keep revolving without having a set number of revolutions. Basically my end goal is to have a continuously revolver which goes through all quotes and then repeats the revolution. I was wondering what changes I can make to the attached link to achieve this.

Comment: Can you provide us your code? As it stands it would be extremely difficult to assist you. Please read How to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `ng-repeat` to loop through set of data available.it will act as a for loop. look at below example code.

```
<div ng-repeat="quotes in parsed['quotes']">
    <div class="quote">{{ quotes }}</div> 
</div>
```

Comment: I do use ng-repeat. That is not the problem. Did you look at the link? The css file has 5 cycles. I don't want to predetermine the number of cycles. THere should be however many items there are in json as the number of cycles.

Comment: sorry for the above answer. to overcome your problem you can create a custom directive and pass the value of json (count) to the directive. inside the directive based on number of count add the required class name to your quote element. Once the loop is executed remove the css class name from the element.

Comment: Can you give me an example?